# Equations in SQL (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table with a cost_maintence column that has cost for the entire year(52) weeks. I also have a table of renters, and a table of renter_units where there is a week_owned column that has the week number the renter rented. I am trying to figure out how I could calculate the cost for each renter.  The equation I came up with is:

> what each person owes = (cost_maintence/52) * #weeks each renter
>   rented

Is there any way I could get the value from a query?

```
create table renters(
    id,
    lname,
    fname,
    phone_num);

create table unit(
    id,
    unit_name,
    unit_num,
    cost_maintence);

create table renters_unit(
    renters_id,
    unit_id,
    week_owned);
```

This is the query I came up with but I have no way of testing it out

```
select r.lname, r.fname, count(ru.week_owned),  
sum(u.cost_maintence/52*count(ru.week_owned))
from renters r, renters_units ru, units u
where r.id = ru.renter_id
and ru.unit_id = u.id
and u.unit_name =unitname
and u.unit_num = unitnum
group by lname
order by lname,fname asc;
```

Comment: Indeed, an example would be good, in particular the renter_units table... do you mean there is a separate row for each week of the year the renter rented a certain unit?

Comment: There is a separate row for each week that is rented

Comment: You can do math with sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example. The inner query will get you amount owed per item, and the outer query sums that to find the total owed per person.

```
SELECT fname, SUM(owes) AS total_due
FROM (
  SELECT r.fname,
  r.id,
  u.unit_name,
  u.cost_maintence/52*COUNT(ru.week_owned) AS owes

  FROM renters AS r
  INNER JOIN renters_unit AS ru ON r.id = ru.renters_id
  INNER JOIN unit AS u ON u.id = ru.unit_id
  GROUP BY r.id, u.id
) AS t
GROUP BY id
```

Try it out with a [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35963/6/0)

Example Schema:

```
create table renters(
id int,
lname varchar(20),
fname varchar(20),
phone_num varchar(20));

create table unit(
id int,
unit_name varchar(30),
unit_num int,
cost_maintence int);

create table renters_unit(
renters_id int,
unit_id int,
week_owned int);

INSERT INTO renters VALUES (1, 'Peterson', 'Chaz', '8675309');

INSERT INTO unit VALUES (1, 'Skateboard', 1337, 52);
INSERT INTO unit VALUES (2, 'Flamethrower', 5432, 104);

INSERT INTO renters_unit VALUES (1, 1, 1);
INSERT INTO renters_unit VALUES (1, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO renters_unit VALUES (1, 1, 4);
INSERT INTO renters_unit VALUES (1, 2, 4);
INSERT INTO renters_unit VALUES (1, 2, 5);
```

By this, we can see that Chaz should owe $7 for the year (had a skateboard for 3 weeks at $1 per week, and a flamethrower for 2 weeks at $2 per week).

The inner query gives the following:

```
FNAME UNIT_NAME    OWES
Chaz  Skateboard   3
Chaz  Flamethrower 4
```

And the outer:

```
FNAME TOTAL_DUE
Chaz  7
```

Comment: When I add more renters and change the renter_units id it still only displays for chaz

Comment: Try it again, I missed a group-by statement while copying :)

Comment: That query looks a lot better than what I had come up with haha

Comment: What is the significance of the as t at the end of the inner query?

Comment: Take it off, and see why :P (Actual reason: MySQL requires all subqueries in the FROM clause to be aliased: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/subqueries_part_1.html)

Comment: @user2337029: FYI, the query shown in my answer achieves the same result.  See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/35963/4/0.  If you want the renter's name, then simply join the `renters` table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT   t.renters_id, SUM(u.cost_maintence)/52
FROM     unit u JOIN renters_unit t ON t.unit_id = u.id
GROUP BY t.renters_id
```